# Currency format in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to format prices in C++

I can use [`std::put_money`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) but the problem is that my number format locale is different from my currency locale.

Say I want to format a price in GBP in French, if I set the locale to French, I get a euro sign. I need the decimal in the user's locale and the currency in the price locale.

I can do that in Java with NumberFormat coming from the decimal locale and then setting the currency I want on it.

Can this be done in C++?

Comment: Can you give an example ? You want `£1,20` to be 1 pound and 20 pence or `£1.20`?

Comment: @SombreroChicken IIUC that'd be £1,20: english money symbol, french decimal point.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, wasn't sure

Comment: Interesting question

Comment: Natively in C++? No, there is probably a library or something out there like that. Or you can do your own custom code to format using `iomanip`.

Comment: @Quentin or rather `1,20 £`, if my locale library isn't lying to me.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, that'd makes more sense. I don't actually know how foreign money amounts should be written :|

Comment: The accepted answer is correct and it is using the standard library. Very good. I don't know how other languages format numbers and prices, so this is exactly what you need the localization tools for. It's not much more complicated than in Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own `moneypunct` facet, inheriting from `std::moneypunct`, and construct a locale using it. Here's such facet you can construct from two locale names. One is responsible for the currency symbol and the other is for everything else.

```
template <class CharT, bool International = false>
class my_moneypunct;

template <class CharT, bool International = false>
class my_moneypunct_byname : public std::moneypunct_byname<CharT, International>
{
  friend class my_moneypunct<CharT, International>;
  using std::moneypunct_byname<CharT, International>::moneypunct_byname;
};

template <class CharT, bool International>
class my_moneypunct : public std::moneypunct_byname<CharT, International>
{
    my_moneypunct_byname<CharT, International> other_moneypunct;
    public:
    explicit my_moneypunct(const char* myName, const char* otherName, std::size_t refs = 0) :
        std::moneypunct_byname<CharT, International>(myName, refs), other_moneypunct(otherName, refs) {}
    typename std::moneypunct_byname<CharT, International>::string_type do_curr_symbol() const override {
        return other_moneypunct.do_curr_symbol();
    }
    virtual ~my_moneypunct() = default;
};
```

You can use it this way:

```
std::moneypunct<char>* mp = new_moneypunct<char>("en_GB.UTF-8", "fr_FR.UTF-8");
// or std::moneypunct<char>* mp = new_moneypunct<char>("fr_FR.UTF-8", "en_GB.UTF-8");
std::locale newloc(std::locale(), mp);
std::cout.imbue(newloc);
std::cout << std::showbase << std::put_money("1234567");
// prints '€12,345.67' or '12 345,67 £'
```

Note this is not tested for memory leaks.

You also can, instead of inheriting `std::moneypunct_byname`, inherit just `std::moneypunct` and forward every overridable method to different `moneypunct` facets you fetch from several locales using `std::use_facet`. Or hard code your currency symbol, or any other way you like.